# Exposing PureScript types to JavaScript

Tags: haskell, purescript

Can I use PureScript types in JS? For example:

```
type SomeType = /*type declaration*/

func :: SomeType
func = /*type construction*/
```

And then in JS do something like this:

```
let a = module.func()
a instanceof module.SomeType === true
```

If not if there is any Haskellish language where I can achieve it (Elm, GHCJS, Idris?)?

Comment: Is this about having PS type information at runtime? I know nothing about PS, but I would assume PS types are erased at compilation time.

Comment: This smells like, "I want to do the thing the thing I'm used to doing, in the new model I'm learning." Tell us what problem you are trying to solve, and there's likely a Haskell-y way of solving it.

Comment: The library must expose JS classes (i.e. functions with prototypes) and objects returned by the library's functions must be instances of these classes. To make things more fun those objects must have methods. I think I'll try to create some helpers in JS and call them by FFI. If it will end badly I'll just stay with TypeScript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general the answer is "no". The runtime representation really depends on what the type is exactly.

For `data` declarations, every constructor would be represented by a JS "class", like this:

```
-- PureScript:
data T = A Int | B

x :: T
x = A 42

// JS:
function A(value0) { this.value0 = value0; }
A.create = function(value0) { return new A(value0); }

function B() { }
B.value = new B();

var x = A.create(42);
```

So you can technically use `instanceof` to distinguish between cases, but not to determine the type itself.

For a `newtype`, on the other hand, the type wrapper will be completely erased, because that's the whole point of `newtype`:

```
-- PureScript:
newtype T = T Int

x :: T
x = T 42

// JS:
var x = 42;
```

And for type synonyms (declared with the `type` keyword), there is no distinct representation. That is, the way such types are represented at runtime is the same as their right-hand side representation:

```
-- PureScript
type T = Int

x :: T
x = 42

// JS:
var x = 42;
```

This also applies to naked records, because they are merely type synonyms too:

```
-- PureScript
type R = { x :: Int, y :: String }

r :: R
r = { x: 42, y: "foo" }

// JS:
var r = { x: 42, y: "foo" }
```

---

**So the bottom line is:** there is no good way to do this. PureScript simply makes no promises about runtime representation. It makes very good promises about program behavior, but not about how it would be implemented in JS (or whatever other backend you happen to be using).

**And this is another problem:** because PureScript doesn't make any promises like that, it's a very bad idea to rely on your (mine) knowledge of the current implementation, because the next version of the compiler may change it completely. PureScript can do this, because it made no promises. See how that works?

For example, I know there is a pull request in the pipeline somewhere that would switch `data` representation to arrays, like this:

```
-- PureScript:
data T = A Int | B

x, y :: T
x = A 42
y = B

// JS:
var x = ["A", 42]
var y = ["B"]
```

If this pull request is ever accepted, your program will be broken.

---

In conclusion I can also tell you that neither Elm, nor Haskell, nor Idris will exhibit the property you're after. Runtime type information is generally not a thing valued in the ML universe. One can argue it's effectively present in Idris, in a way, but not in the way you expect.

You may want to try [F#/Fable](https://fable.io/): it's a little bit stronger in this regard, but still not as good as on its native .NET runtime. I don't think you can just check types of F# objects from JS out of the blue, but I know that Fable does support accessing RTTI from F# itself (at extra performance cost), so you can at least make functions to do that and export them to JS.

If you can expand a bit on what your actual problem is, then perhaps I (or someone else) would be able to suggest an alternative solution.

Comment: "PureScript simply makes no promises about runtime representation" as someone who has worked on PureScript, I disagree with that. Part of the point of PureScript is to have simple rules to get to the runtime presentation. I WOULD totally use instanceof on data constructors, I have no problem with that. I don't consider it to be an implementation detail, I consider it to be a core part of PureScript.